# How to pass an int array to void * argument of a mock method in google mock testing?

Tags: googlemock

I'm trying to mock an SPI interface - Read, Write, Transfer using gmock C++ framework

For instance, SPI - Read signature is
bool SPI_Read(void* rdata, int num_bytes);

I have defined

```
int device_info[5] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05};

ACTION_P(SetArg0ToIntWithSizeArg1, value) { strcpy_s(static_cast<int*>(arg1), arg2, value); }

EXPECT_CALL(spi_obj, SPI_Read(_,_))
      .Times(1)
      .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArg0ToIntWithSizeArg1(device_info),Return(true)));
```

I get compile error: `‘strcpy_s’ was not declared in this scope`.

and is it is a right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy_s` was a *Microsoft Extension* to C, to be able to detect certain buffer overflow errors at runtime, which has "recently" be *standardized as optional feature* in C11. The error message you cite does *not* indicate any problem with Google Test or Goolge Mock, but obviously your compiler is not configured to understand `strcpy_s`. Please note that while `strcpy_s` is an option in C11, it is not in any C++ standard. You need to compile the source code as C++ to be able to use Google Test or Google Mock.

It depends on your compiler how to enable `strcpy_s` in C++ mode (or whether it is possible at all).